# Margins around images

Tags: media, wysiwyg

I have Drupal 8.1.2; the Breakpoint and Responsive Image modules are installed.

When an image is inserted using CKEditor inline images there is no margin between the image and the text.

I have looked for the CSS for the image but can only locate                {figure.caption.caption-img.align-left} for example.

Where do I go to set margins around images?

Comment: Apparently there is not yet any CSS defined for these elements. You can go ahead and add `figure (margin: 5px;}` to your theme's CSS file to give all figures a margin.